# Obtain AppleTV system logs

Tags: appletv, logs

I have an Apple TV (4th generation). Since this is a true iOS device, I suppose it has system log like every Apple device. The device has some issues with waking up and I want to know the reason why it does. I hope this can be found in the logs.

My question is: is there any way to watch the log files? I know, that I can see the output in Xcode when I connect the Mac via USB and run Xcode, but this goes only for what's happening right now, and there is no way to scroll back to the time before I connected it. (I obviously need that.)

Answer (score 1):

Open Xcode -> Window -> Devices and Simulators. Next, on your Apple TV, go to the Settings app, then Remote App and Devices. Your Apple TV should then automatically appear as an option in Xcode.